# swift irregular json parse

Tags: json, swift, parsing

Could someone tell me how to parse Json like this? Appreciate any help!
How could I build a Codable struct for this?

```
{
"meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "total_pages": 4,
    "per_page": 10,
    "total_records": 38
},
"breweries": [
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Saint Arnold"
    },
    {
        "id": 52892,
        "name": "Buffalo Bayou",
        "valueQuantity":
        {
             "value":4.33,
             "unit":"mg/dL"
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Hello, your json is not correct a "," is missing after  `"name": "Buffalo Bayou"`. To parse a JSON in swift you can use codable.

Comment: Hey, json is invalid.. Try adding a comma after ```"name": "Buffalo Bayou"```

Comment: sorry, I'm just new here. I don't know the rules. I didn't ask this question very properly. I'll try better next time.

Comment: @肖鼎鼎 These will help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

```
let model = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: jsonData)


import Foundation

// MARK: - MyModel
struct MyModel: Codable {
    let meta: Meta
    let breweries: [Brewery]
}

// MARK: - Brewery
struct Brewery: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let valueQuantity: ValueQuantity?
}

// MARK: - ValueQuantity
struct ValueQuantity: Codable {
    let value: Double
    let unit: String
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    let page, totalPages, perPage, totalRecords: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case page
        case totalPages = "total_pages"
        case perPage = "per_page"
        case totalRecords = "total_records"
    }
}
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: I'll try it! Thank you very much for your help!